# Magento keeps creating a log file even tho log setting set to disabled

Tags: magento, logging

Hello I have an issue where my magento log is creating lots of the same errors over and over again every second.

I just want to disable the log for now. However disabling:

System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Log Setting -> Enabled -> No

seems to do nothing and the log keeps generating. I'm wondering if anyone knows why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

That will disable only 2 Magento standard log files: **system** and **exception**.

***Erase*** them both via ftp and ***clear cache***.

Any other module/extension log files will remain though.

Comment: I have tried this and the system.log is still getting generated. The only way i have of stopping it is to remove the write permissions. Would like a better way though.